# Using a script.js file globally in every react component

Tags: reactjs, pug

I am working on a React project. I have a file  script.js which I want to use in every component of my application. This script.js has multiple plugins and codes in it. For example, there is a plugin code for portlet (a jquery plugin) in it. Each part of scripts code is used by some components. I want declare this script.js globally and then each component should refer to this script if there is some code relevant to that component.

I have included this script.js in my index.jade file.

```
script(src="/public/scripts.js")
```

How should I include it in every component or how should every component refer to it?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of each file you need the methods in, declare each method you need

```
 import {functionName, functionName1, functionName2} from '../folder/filename.jsx'
```

Then you can use the functions anywhere in that file like this

```
var number = functionName();
```